# Não consigo alterar o código do form C#

Tags: c#

Boa noite pessoal poderiam me ajudar?
Bom, estou usando C# com banco de dados SQL Server, tenho um formulário com dois campos codigoCdd e descricaoCdd ambos do tipo texto, eu consigo incluir e excluir dados desses campos sem problemas, mas quando vou alterar os dois, somente o campo descricaoCdd altera e o codigoCdd não altera. O que pode ser? Estou usando programação em camadas, vou postar a classe, a camada de dados, a camada de negócio e a camada do código do botão. Creio que o problema seja na query update. Muito obrigado desde já.

Classe:

```
namespace Biblioteca.Modelos
{
     public class CddModelos
     {
         private string _codigoCdd;

         public string CodigoCdd
         {
             get { return _codigoCdd; }
             set { _codigoCdd = value; }
         }



         private string _descricaoCdd;

         public string DescricaoCdd
         {
             get { return _descricaoCdd; }
             set { _descricaoCdd = value; }
         }
    }
}
```

Camada de dados:

```
namespace Biblioteca.DAL
{
    public class CddDAL
    {
        public void Alterar_cdd(CddModelos cdd)
        {
            // conexao
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();

            try
            {
                cn.ConnectionString = Dados.StringDeConexao;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                cmd.Connection = cn;

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Cdd SET CD_CDD = @CD_CDD, DS_CDD = @DS_CDD WHERE CD_CDD = @CD_CDD;";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CD_CDD", cdd.CodigoCdd);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DS_CDD", cdd.DescricaoCdd);

                cn.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Servidor SQL Erro:" + ex.Number);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Camada de negócio:

```
namespace Biblioteca.BLL
{
    public class CddBLL
    {
        public void Alterar_cdd(CddModelos cdd)
        {
            CddDAL obj = new CddDAL();

            obj.Alterar_cdd(cdd);
        }
    }

}
```

Camada do código do botão:

```
namespace UIWindows
{
    public partial class CddForm : Form
    {
        public CddForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bt_alterar_cdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             if (textBoxCodigo_cdd.Text.Length == 0)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("O cdd deve ser selecionado para alteração.");
             }

             else

                try
                {
                    CddModelos cdd = new CddModelos();

                    cdd.CodigoCdd = textBoxCodigo_cdd.Text;
                    cdd.DescricaoCdd = textBoxDescricao_cdd.Text;

                    CddBLL obj = new CddBLL();

                    obj.Alterar_cdd(cdd);

                    MessageBox.Show("O cdd foi alterado com sucesso!");

                    AtualizaGridCdd();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.Message);
                }

    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando o método é chamado e você tenta alterar:

```
UPDATE Cdd SET CD_CDD = @CD_CDD, DS_CDD = @DS_CDD WHERE CD_CDD = @CD_CDD;
```

Você está buscando pelo novo código CD_CDD, o mesmo que você quer alterar:
`WHERE CD_CDD = @CD_CDD`, ele pode não estar achando na base de dados.

O ideal é que seu método receba o CD_CDD antigo, para que você busque pelo identificador do código anterior e atualize para o novo.

Abraços!

Comment: O cara muito obrigado por ajudar, o meu patrão disse que esse campo CD_CDD não precisa ser alterado. Abraço